Regex - Excluding text inside a word WITHOUT having to split them up into 2 capture groups and combining them using a programming language
Let's say I have the following text:
abc123def
abc1234567890def

In this text, I want to JUST capture the "abc" and the "def" parts of the text, completely excluding the numbers. This could be done with the following expression: (abc)[0-9]*(def).
Quick Note before I move on: I'm aware that you could also use (\D) or something similar to achieve the same result. But for the sake of this example, pretend you cannot take advantage of the fact that the group I'm getting rid of isn't the same character type as the rest of the word. This was just done to better illustrate my problem.
The problem with this, however, is that it splits "abc" and "def" into different capture groups.  Thanks to the situation I'm using this regex for, I cannot use any code to merge the 2 reg-ex groups together. That means I'm trying to convert the reg-ex I already have to output abcdef instead of abc and def.
I've tried...

(abc([0-9]*)def), hoping that the capture groups didn't include the number string because it's in its own capture group

Result: abc123def and abc1234567890def


(abc(?=[0-9]*)def), hoping to "look ahead" the number string

Result: no result


(abc\2)[0-9]*(def) and (abc)[0-9]*(\1def), hoping that the capture with the backreference would include the results from the other group

Result: abc for (abc\2)[0-9]*(def) and no result for (abc)[0-9]*(\1def)


(abc(?:[0-9]*)def), because I misunderstood the documentation thinking that "non-capture group" meant that it would skip whatever's inside it

Result: abc123def and abc1234567890def



Nothing I've tried worked so far, either returning "abc" (no "def") or nothing at all. So, how could I return "abc" and "def" while excluding the numbers between them all in the same capture group? I'm not sure if this matters, but the reg-ex used in this post was tested using https://regexr.com/ with the global and multiline expression flags checked.

Please [edit] your question to include several example lines and the expecting resulting group matches for these lines. Include all the group matches entries including the index 0, which matches the whole matched string, and all the other indices (depending on how many groups you have defined or want to define). It is unclear how exactly you want to match "abcdef". Also write if it is okay if the found match group entry would be at a different index or not (like index 2 instead of 0`, depending on the group matching in the regex)

To combine the two capturing groups, do a replace operation with \1\2 (or $1$2 in some regex engines).  If you have to do this with a match operation rather than a replace, this simply isn't possible - since the result of a match is characterized entirely by the starting/ending indices in the text, you can't skip anything.

you can not have a single match for 2 disjoined parts.

Exactly which regex tool are you using? Please tag the question accordingly. You should also provide more context as to what you're using the regex for.

If you need a pure regex solution, and your regex engine supports lookarounds, you could try this pattern:
(?<=abc)\d+(?=def)

This pattern says to:

(?<=abc) assert that abc precedes
\d+ then match one or more digits
(?=def) assert that def follows the digits

Demo

What about matching the numbers and replacing them with nothing? That way your final string will contain the following, exactly as if it had been captured as you describe.
abcdef
abcdef

So, in your programming language, do a regex replacement searching for /(?<=abc)[0-9]*(?=def)/gm and replacing it with an empty string.
See this working on regex101.
